# partial word search with haystack/elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, django-haystack

We are currently running haystack with an elasticsearch backend.  We are having trouble getting the partial word search to run correctly.

We currently have an index that has an EdgeNgramField.  I have tried doing a search on this field, but I'm not finding any results unless it's an exact match.  I'm trying to use this to find products so for example: I type "sun", I won't get the result for "sunglasses".

I started using curl commands directly on the elasticsearch to see if I could figure out what was happening.  I even created my own index directly with curl, along with an ngram analyzer and I receive the proper results using partial word searches.

Another interesting thing is that: if I run the _mapping command using curl on my test index directly on elasticsearch that I created directly with curl, i get the following: "testfield":{"type":"string", "analyzer":"test_analyzer"}, however, if I run the mapping command on the index created by haystack, it only has "type":"string".  It says nothing about the edgengram_analyzer that it should be using.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a bug in haystack in elasticsearch_backend.py which is not using pyelasticsearch properly line 868 looks like:

```
self.conn.put_mapping('modelresult', current_mapping, index=self.index_name)
```

And if you replace it by:

```
self.conn.put_mapping(doc_type='modelresult', mapping=current_mapping, index=self.index_name)
```

which is how pyelasticsearch expects it, then you will see that the edgengram_analyzer is added to your EdgeNgramField field. At least it works for me.

Comment: do as @racedo mentioned. and don't forget to update ur index and it will work

Comment: The problem I am currently facing is the autocomplete returns results only if the word matches the starting of product. but else it won't work.
so If I search for 'sun', it will return 'sunglasses'. but If I search for 'glass', I get No results. although it should have returned 'sunglasses' too ??!

Comment: racedo, that partly solved the problem.  Thanks!  But I'm now facing what Salma mentioned, which is that it only does a partial match on the beginning of the word.

Comment: No problem. What you want is ngram and not edge ngram. Edge NGram is meant to match either at the beginning or ending of a word and ngram means a group of contiguous letters within a word (in information extraction terms at least). btw if this doesn't anwser your second question please create a new question so that we can discuss it with answers.

Comment: was this fixed in the canonical elasticsearch backend? or do i still have to make this change?

Comment: To answer my own subquestion, no it hasn't see https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py#L132

Comment: I still only get NGram to give results on strings of length 3, or full words, not arbitrary lengths strings